# iPhone view won't rotate

Tags: iphone, view, rotation

This is a continuation from a previous question that I asked: [iPhone View Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730190/iphone-view-strategy)

I am now using the following method to switch between views:

```
UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
[window setRootViewController:[self gameViewController]];
[[[self gameViewController] view] becomeFirstResponder];
```

The problem I am having is that none of my views rotate properly (the status bar rotates but nothing else). The initial view is fine but any views that I navigate to using the above method have the problem with rotation.

I have implemented the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method in all of my view controllers as follows:

```
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES to allow autorotation
    return YES;
}
```

This has become a bit of a sticking point for me. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Alan

Comment: [Exact duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773012/iphone-view-wont-rotate)

Comment: Sorry about that, deleted the other one!

Comment: That's not the normal way to switch views...

Comment: What is the normal way to switch views?

Answer (score 1):

It might be how you are displaying your views.  I was having this problem with a popover that was displaying a modal window.  Still not sure what was causing the problem, think it was an apple bug.  Why don't you try doing something like this:

```
[window addSubview:gameViewController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

This is assuming that your gameViewController is initialized somewhere else in your code. Not sure if that is what you are looking for but it may work.

Answer (score 0):

do you have UITabBarController in there?

Comment: I am not using UITabBarController. I am just using the view controllers on their own.

Answer (score 0):

The shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method should go in the current view controller for the views, not the UIViews themselves.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was talking about my view controllers not views. I have edited my original post.